# Mag custom options issue

Tags: php, arrays, magento, loops, csv

I am using the following code to get and process the custom options

```
$orderIncrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
                $orderReal = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);    


    $orderItems = $orderReal->getAllItems();   

    $sk = "";
    foreach ($orderItems as $item)
                {
      $options = $item->getProductOptions();      
      foreach ($options as $option) {
       if (is_array($option)) {
       $firstElement = array_shift($option);

   foreach ($option as $firstElement){
           if (isset($firstElement['label']) && isset($firstElement['option_value'])){
         if ($firstElement['label'] == 'Delivery Date') {
             $deliveryDate = $firstElement['option_value'];

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                  }
                }
```

and my usage is to write it to CSV like this

```
if (isset($deliveryDate)) {
    $outputString.= '"'.$deliveryDate.'",'; 
} else {
    $outputString.= '"deliverydate error",'; 
}
```

now, I have made sure that

- Label Delivery Date is available in data base  "Catalog Product Option Title Table"
- custom option Delivery Date has values in "Catalog Product Option
  Table"

it looks like Delivery date is not being accessed via the script so my custom message 'deliverydate error' saves in CSV

in fact I am trying to debug mag extension that is not working properly...

to me, code is okay, but not sure why its not working....

can anybody guide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's not the perfect solution, this will return your custom option value for the ordered item, assuming that your product custom option is a type "field".

```
foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
  $optionsArray = $item->getProductOptions();
  if(isset($optionsArray['options'])) {
    foreach ($optionsArray['options'] as $option) {
      if($option['label'] == 'Delivery Date') {
        $deliveryDate = $option['value'];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, can you tell me is there any error in my code? why its not working? I am sure its okay

Comment: The whole logic that you have is useless. Just put my foreach loop instead of yours and it should work perfectly.